# Why this particular definition for the derivative on a group ring?

Tags: group-theory, derivatives, group-rings

I am reading *Introduction to Knot Theory* by Crowell and Fox, and I am a bit confused at the way they define a derivative on a group ring (and on a group). I understand a derivative (or derivation maybe more properly) to be a linear map which satisfies the Leibniz rule. However, they first define the derivative on a group to be $D:G\to JG$
$$D(g_1g_2)=Dg_1+g_1Dg_2$$
which can be uniquely extended to the map on the group ring $D:JG\to JG$ as
$$D(v_1v_2)=(Dv_1)\mathfrak{t}(v_2)+v_1Dv_2$$
where $\mathfrak{t}$ is the trivializer
$$\mathfrak{t}(\sum_i n_ig_i)=\sum n_i.$$
So I understand how this is all well-defined, and I am convinced it is a derivative (that's rather clear I guess). But why choose this, instead of just
$$D(g_1g_2)=(Dg_1)g_2+g_1(Dg_2)$$
With a natural (unique, I think) extension to
$$D(v_1v_2)=(Dv_1)v_2+v_1(Dv_2)$$
Perhaps they are going after some specific structure here, but does anyone have a reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: Hmm. This seems odd to me. You have two binary operations at play here: the group operation and $+$ but $D$ maps the group to itself. How are they related?

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful if I clarify the group ring - these are elements $v:G\to J$, with $J$ the integers, defined by $(v_1+v_2)g=v_1g+v_2g$ and $(v_1v_2)g=\sum_i(v_1h_i)(v_2h_i^{-1}g)$. These tell you how the products in the ring and the group operations are related.

Comment: I am taking issue with your very first definition. It seems really fishy. A group has only one operation on it but you're using two. I know what the group ring is, though that is a very strange presentation for a group ring.

Comment: Oh I see - it was an error in transcription, my fault. The derivative is always $D:JG\to JG$, but restricted to group elements you get my first expression. I'll change that....

Comment: I see that now. I'm looking at the book now. It definitely is strange to me that it doesn't obey the Leibniz rule but this is not too uncommon in the setting of generalized derivatives. In quantum gravity, for instance, they have coproducts which behave *almost* like the Leibniz rule but may have extra terms.

Comment: After reading ahead, I can't say I understand exactly why they chose that definition. Naively, one would think that your definition is the most logical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a finite cyclic group generated by $g$ of order $n$ so that $g^{-1} = g^{n-1}$. Let $\Bbb{Z}[G]$ denote its group ring. The obvious choice of derivative would be $D = \frac{d}{dg}$ (meaning $Dg = 1$). We would like to have that $\frac{d}{dg} g^{-1} = \frac{d}{dg} g^{n-1}$ since these two elements are technically the same. (This says that $D$ is well-defined in loose terms.) If we use your proposed definition

$$D(g_1g_2) = D g_1\cdot g_2 + g_1\cdot Dg_2$$

applied to this situation, induction gives for $m < n$

$$D (g^m) = mg^{m-1}.$$

This is to be expected from what we know about $\Bbb R$. Particularly, we have that

$$D(g^{n-1}) = (n-1)g^{n-2} = (n-1)g^{-2}.$$

Additionally,

$$D(1) = D(1\cdot 1) = D(1)\cdot 1 + 1\cdot D(1).$$

That is to say that $D(1) = D(1) + D(1)$ so $D(1) = 0$ in the ring. Thus

$$0 = D(1) = D(g^{-1}g) = D(g^{-1})\cdot g + g^{-1}\cdot D(g) = D(g^{-1})\cdot g + g^{-1}.$$

That is to say that

$$ - g^{-1} = g\cdot D(g^{-1}) \Longrightarrow -g^{-2} = D(g^{-1}). $$

The above formula agrees with our *intuition* from $\Bbb R$, however, as one often finds in harmonic analysis, the nicety of $\Bbb R$ can really lead you astray into thinking things are simpler than they actually are. The two expressions for $D(g^{-1})$ do not match so blindly applying the Leibniz rule doesn't work in this setting. It seems that the rigidity of the group ring *forces* you somewhat into their "unnatural" definition for the derivative.

---

If we go by their definition, the picture changes a bit:

$$D(g^2) = D(g\cdot g) = D(g) + g\cdot D(g) = 1 + g.$$

Likewise

$$D(g^3) = D(g\cdot g^2) = D(g) + g\cdot D(g^2) = 1 + g + g^2.$$

Repeating we get (for $m < n$)

$$D(g^m) = 1 + g + \cdots + g^{m-1}.$$

Thus we have

$$D(g^{n-1}) = 1 + g + \cdots + g^{n-2}.$$

By the formula in their text

$$D(g^{-1}) = -g^{-1}\cdot D(g) = -g^{-1}.$$

This doesn't seem to agree with $D(g^{n-1})$ but it does! By their (very reasonable and suggestive) shorthand,

$$\sum_{i=0}^k g^i = \frac{g^{k+1}-1}{g-1}.$$

Thus

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} g^i = \frac{g^{n-1}-1}{g-1} = g^{-1}\frac{g^n - g}{g-1} = g^{-1}\frac{1 - g}{g-1} = -g^{-1}.$$

So we get that $D(g^{-1}) = D(g^{n-1})$ as we should.

Comment: Ah very nice catch - and I suppose that although we aren't thinking about $G$ as cyclic in this context, we'd prefer a derivative which works in all group rings. Or, maybe there is a similar argument which applies to free groups, which are particularly relevant for knot theory.

Comment: I've edited my answer a bit to add the calculation for their definition of the derivative. I think that this gives enough credence to the idea and I would be surprised if it wasn't the justification for it, more or less.