# Similarities/differences between derivations in rings vs. group rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, definition

I have come across two types of maps between rings, both of which try to model derivatives of real functions, both of which do this by modelling the Leibnitz rule, and both of which are called *derivations*. I will briefly give their definitions below, but my question is: **are these two definitions fundamentally the same/similar thing(s) in disguise, or are they completely different and just happen to have similar names?**

**Definition 1:** (derivation in a ring)
Let $R$ be a ring, a map $D:R\to R$ is a *derivation* if it satisfies $D(a+b)=D(a)+D(b)$, together with
$$
D(ab)=D(a)b+aD(b).
$$

**Definition 2:** (derivation in a group ring)
Let $R$ be a ring, $G$ a group, and $R[G]$ the corresponding group ring. Denote by $\epsilon:R[G]\to R$ the augmentation map. A map $D:R[G]\to R[G]$ is a *derivation* if it satisfies $D(a+b)=D(a)+D(b)$, together with
$$
D(ab)=D(a)\epsilon(b)+aD(b).
$$

I should say that I have spent quite some time thinking about the second definition in the context of Fox calculus (ie for the integral group ring $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{F}_n]$ of a free group), but while trying to research that subject I kept coming across things discussing the first definition which seems to be the one much more widely used in the general study of abstract algebra.

Comment: Yes, a derivation usually means 1. in algebra. Take as an example derivations of associative algebras or Lie algebras. It is really the Leibniz rule. For groups rings, there are other versions, see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244235/why-this-particular-definition-for-the-derivative-on-a-group-ring).

Comment: Your second thing would likely be called a *skew-derivation* or an $\epsilon$-derivation.  It's defined [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233218355_Skew_derivations_of_prime_rings) for example, but I really don't know if it makes a difference where that $\epsilon$ map appears there, or on the other term.  I half expect someone has looked at skew derivations with maps skewing both $a$ and $b$ separately.

Comment: I have not seen Definition 2 before, but I agree that it looks like it is linearly extending  Fox derivatives from domain $F_n$ to domain $\mathbb{Z}[F_n]$.  For an arbitrary Fox derivative you would have a homomorphism $\theta\colon F_n\to G$, extending linearly to a homomorphism $\Theta\colon \mathbb{Z}[F_n]\to \mathbb{Z}[G]$  and the rule would then be: $$
D(ab)=D(a)\epsilon(b)+\Theta(a)D(b).
$$

Comment: @tkf Definition 2 is as stated in Fox' paper (although he only used $R=\mathbb{Z}$), I don't think there is a well defined restriction of this notion of derivative to just $\mathbb{F}_n$, for example $\partial(xyx)\partial y= 1+xy\in\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{F}_2=\mathbb{F}_2$. Also I'm pretty sure that a derivation on $\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{F}_n$ does not descend to a derivation on $\mathbb{Z}G$ under $\theta$ because it will not respect non-trivial relations in $G$, by which I mean there will be non-trivial words in $\mathbb{F}_n$, say $r$, which are trivial in $G$, but $D(r)\neq0$.

Comment: @DavidSheard I didn't know he defined it on group rings originally.  The versions I have used just apply the derivative to words in free groups, rather than linear combinations of words.  Of course the output always lives in a group ring.  You are right, $D(r)$ is not necessarily $0$ for $r$ a relator.  In fact the $\partial_{g_i}(R_j)$ are precisely the entries of the $\partial_2$ matrix whose kernel is the second homotopy module of the presentation $G=\langle \{g_i|i\in I \}| \{R_ j| j\in J\}\rangle$.  Why is there a problem with this not being $0$?

Comment: @DavidSheard I think in both cases the confusion was created by me not making clear the domains and codomains of the derivatives.  So the version I usually use goes $F_n\to \mathbb{Z}[G]$.  On seeing your question, I noted that one can extend this linearly to $\mathbb{Z}[F_n]\to \mathbb{Z}[G]$ and obtain precisely the condition you wrote above (when $\theta$ is the identity) and the one I wrote for general $\theta$.  I trust neither of your objections apply to either of these classes of derivative.

Comment: @tkf Yes I agree. The problem with $D(r)\neq 0$ aplies only if you were trying to define a derivative $D_\theta:\mathbb{Z}[G]\to\mathbb{Z}[G]$ which was somehow induced from the derivative $D:\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{F}_n]\to\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{F}_n]$ by $\theta$. For $D_\theta$ to be well-defined it would have to be zero on all relators. I fell I understand this side of things quite well, my question was more about whether on some level thee Fox derivatives are closely related to the normal definition of a derivation in a ring. The post linked in the first comment suggests they are unrelated

Comment: @DavidSheard They model different intuitions.  Definition 1 is abstracting the notion of a vector field, whilst Definition 2  is for computing the boundary of a lift of a cell.  I suppose Stoke's theorem gives you some sort of indirect relation between differential forms and chains generated by cells.  Googling non-Abelian Stokes theorem gives you some hits like https://academic.oup.com/ptp/article/103/1/151/1925448.  Probably a long shot though.